# Using Dependencies

Tags: java, android-studio, dependencies

When I try using using the dependency `implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:2.1'` or `implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker-support:1.7.1'` I will get a warning message that says "Failed to resolve: com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker-support:1.7.1
Show in Project Structure dialog</ a >
Affected Modules: app</ a >"
How do I get rid of this warning?
This is the link to the github I am working on **https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker**

I tried adding the build.gradle from the folder but I don't know where to add it, when I copy and paste the entire thing I get an error saying
"Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'app\build.gradle'"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to the Gradle Scripts folder and click settings.gradle. Copy and paste `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` in the repositories{}. Now you can go back to build.gradle in your Gradle Scripts folder to add in your implementations.